# Traveling to another solar system without "spatial holes" and without falling in the twin paradox

Tags: special-relativity, interstellar-travel

I understand that traveling to the nearest solar system (Alpha Centauri, 4.37 light-years from the Sun) is very complex not only because the need of proper thrusting and human and/or robot safety, but also because a spaceship could bump in a lot of rocks scattered in space and get destroyed, hence an automatic spatial navigation calculation (computation) system will be needed to navigate without hitting any such rock,

Assuming the "perfect" thrusting automatic spatial navigation calculation (computation) system are both acquired:
Should humans be able to go back and forth to Alpha Centauri without using "spatial holes" (wormhole and maybe also black-white hole if the concept is real) but also without falling in the twin paradox,
so to be back into the solar system without passing "huge" amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space is remarkably empty so the need for "rock avoidance" is much smaller then you think.

Alpha Centauri is about  4 light years away so it will take you at least 8 years to go back and forth as measured by a stationary observer on earth. Time observed by the passenger will be less. How much less depends on how close you get to light speed.

If you want to avoid the "twin paradox" (i.e. time difference between a stationary and a moving observer) then you need to travel much slower then light speed. However, the trip will take much longer than. If you manage to travel at 1% light speed, it would take 800 years for a round trip.

Comment: Hello; thanks for the answer - just one comment; I recall hearing some phyisicst in YouTube (perhaps Michio Kaku or Neil Degrasse Tyson) talking about how hard it can be to get o another solar system or galaxy because of obstacles in the way; also I read about dark planets which can also be a massive theoretical obstacle. So maybe the two `is`s in the first passage should be changed to two `maybe`s.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you count as huge.

If you travel at $.99c$, you'll age $1.2$ years while your friends on earth age $8.8$ years.

If you travel at $.75c$, you'll age $7.7$ years while your friends on earth age $11.7$ years.

If you travel at $.5c$, you'll age $15.1$ years while your friends on earth age $17.5$ years.

If you travel at $.25c$, you'll age $33.8$ years while your friends on earth age $35$ years.

If you travel at $.01c$, you'll age $873.96$ years while your friends on earth age $874$ years.